# Webview inside Scrollview in a fragment is collapsing when screen orientation changes from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-scrollview, exoplayer

I have two fragments in a view pager VideoFragment and StoryFragment. 
In Videofragment i am setting the below lines and video view to match the parent.-

```
 getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
             getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

After user moves to portrait i am clearing the flag-

```
metrics2 = new DisplayMetrics();
                getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()
                        .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
                getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics2);
                getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

All these are happening in the VideoFragment, but when i swipe the view pager, next fragment is the story fragment which has the below layout-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_share_top"
        layout="@layout/story_share_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_story"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_id"
        android:layout_below="@id/include_share_top"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_scrollview_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ad_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:background="@color/light_grey"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <!-- This layout has imageview, this is not visible -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/flVideo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/black">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/story_video_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivBackStoryImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivPlay1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/video"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pbPlay"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/flScroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/include_share_middle"
                    layout="@layout/story_share_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible" />


                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/include_share_middle"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <!-- This is webview which is covering whole space, it actually pushes the image view out of screen -->
                    <com.timesnowmobile.TimesNow.widgets.ObservableWebView
                        android:id="@+id/wvStoryhtml"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_subscribe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/red_card_shape"
                        android:text="Subscribe"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.timesnowmobile.TimesNow.widgets.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.50"
            android:src="@drawable/related_stories" />
    </com.timesnowmobile.TimesNow.widgets.FloatingActionButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Webview is occupying the entire screen moving all views to the top. When i scroll down i can see the image. This happens only when i go to landscape mode in the videofragment. I am using Exoplayer for videos.

**Edit 1**
Now i changed the `<ScrollView>` to `<NestedScrollView>` and added this attribute android:fillViewport="true" . 
After returning from landscape to portrait , its not collapsing but scrolling isn't working at all.